# Migrations Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.4

estou com problema ao tentar rodar minhas migrations, quando eu executo:

> php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Ocorre o erro abaixo:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `cities`)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

**CreateCitiesTable**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cities');
    }
```

**CreatePlacesTable**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('places', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('icon');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('places');
}
```

**CreateClientsTable**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('zipcode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
}
```

**CreateCompaniesTable**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('zipcode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No Laravel 5.5 teremos uma função chamada:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Que fará um `drop` nas tabelas e iniciará nova migração.

Este erro acontece porque o comando `refresh` tenta dar um `rollback` e muitas vezes em função de algum erro anterior, não consegue de fato rodar os scripts..

Como na versão 5.4 não temos ainda o `migrate:fresh` tente excluir todas as tabelas manualmente ou rodar `drop` e um `create` no banco de dados antes de rodar o `migrate` novamente.